# Split text with a single code

Tags: javascript

```
var objname = "Image1-123456-789.png"
```

quick question i wanted to split this text without match them together again.

here is my code

```
var typename = objname.split("-");

//so it will be Image1,123456,789.png

var SplitNumber = typename[1]+'-'+typename[2];
var fullNumber = SplitCode.split('.')[0];
```

to get what i wanted

my intention is to get number is there anyway i can split them without join them and split again ?

can a single code do that perfectly ? my code look like so many job.

i need to get the 123456-789.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

This method extracts the characters in a string between "start" and "end", not including "end" itself.

```js
var objname = "Image1-123456-789.png";
var newname = objname.substring(objname.indexOf("-")+1, objname.indexOf("."));
alert(newname);
```

Comment: thank is what i needed ~ have a beautiful day for you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate can be using `Join`. You can use `slice` to fetch range of values in array and then join them using `-`.

```js
var objname = "Image1-123456-789.png";
var fullnumber = objname.split("-").slice(1).join("-").split(".")[0];
alert(fullnumber)
```

#### Reference

[Join Array from startIndex to endIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342728/join-array-from-startindex-to-endindex)

Answer (score -2):

Here is your solution

```
var objname = "Image1-123456-789.png";
var typename= objname.split("-");


var again=typename[2];
var again_sep= again.split(".");

var fullNumber =typename[1]+'-'+again_sep[0];
```