# how to iterate a string array and concat elements together in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, iteration

getPath(array, 0) will return "A"
 getPath(array, 1) will return "AB"
 getPath(array, 2) will return "ABC"

```
function getPath(arr, idx){  
  // todo ...     
}  
var array = ["A","B","C"];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join Array from startIndex to endIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342728/join-array-from-startindex-to-endindex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getPath(arr, idx){  
  return (arr.slice(0, idx+1).join(""));  
}
```

Yes, you're right, thx Redu

Answer (score 0):

Plain old for loop style:

```
 function getPath(arr, idx){
   var output="";  
    for(i=0;i<idx;i++){
    output= output + array[i]
    }
  return output;
}  
var array = ["A","B","C"];
```